# weird behaviour of array slicing

Tags: arrays, f#, slice

```
> let a = [| 'a'..'d' |];;
val a : char [] = [|'a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'|]
```

Do trivial slicing:

```
> a.[1..2], [1..2];;
val it : char [] * int list = ([|'b'; 'c'|], [1; 2])
```

Now try it with empty region:

```
> a.[1..0], [1..0];;
val it : char [] * int list = ([||], [])
```

Seems working and reasonable - we got two empty sequences.

But it fails here:

```
> a.[5..0];;
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0018>.$FSI_0018.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

Of course, there is a workaround `[| for i in [5..0] -> a.[i] |]`. But I miss the point why `a.[5..0]` fails? Why not just return empty array? Any reasons for such behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug.

*Though array slicing and range expression are different concepts (you cannot use `a.[1..2..5]` for example), they should behave consistently.*

Notice that the exception happens with `a.[start..finish]` when `finish - start <= -2` (`a.[3..1]` fails) and array slicing works fine if `finish - start = -1` (`a.[5..4] = [||]`).

Array slicing is done by using [GetArraySlice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340510.aspx) function in [prim-types.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs):

```
let inline GetArraySlice (arr: _[]) start finish = 
    let start  = (match start with None -> 0 | Some n -> n) 
    let finish = (match finish with None -> arr.Length - 1 | Some n -> n) 
    GetArraySub arr start (finish - start + 1)
```

while `GetArraySub` is implemented in the same module as follows:

```
let inline GetArraySub arr (start:int) (len:int) =
    let dst = zeroCreate len   
    for i = 0 to len - 1 do 
        SetArray dst i (GetArray arr (start + i))
    dst
```

If `finish - start = -1`, we have `len = 0` in `GetArraySub` and `zeroCreate 0` returns an empty array. It's no longer the case with `finish - start <= -2` which leads to `len < 0` and `zeroCreate len` fails.

This could be fixed by always returning an empty array whenever `finish - start <= -1`.

Comment: Do you know where is "official" bug tracker for F#?

Comment: You can send a bug report to fsbugs (at) microsoft (dot) com.